# Is there any restrictions in uploading files to AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I wanted to train a TensorFlow model in AWS. But to do so, I have to first upload the imagenet-vgg `.mat` file which is about 580 MB. So I was wondering if there are any restrictions in uploading such files? Any specific fees or limits? The best way to know would be to try myself but I am afraid that I could be charged in doing so.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT: 
[image]
There is an option next to `New` where you can `Upload` files. That is what I meant by uploading.

Comment: What do you mean by "uploading files to AWS instances?" If you are referring to an Amazon EC2 instance, it is just a virtual computer running the Operating System you selected. AWS does not limit (nor does it have access to) what you do on that instance. Presumably, you would actually logon to the instance and _download_ the file, rather than _uploading to_ the instance.

Comment: @DavidMakogon umm, Amazon SageMaker? if that is what you are asking

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edited the question and made it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, go ahead and upload.

You are running an application (Jupyter) on your own EC2 instance. What you do on that is up to you, as long as it doesn't violate Terms of Service (gambling, illegal activities, etc).

Worst case, you might run out of disk space.

Comment: I see, and would the files still dwell there as long as I dont DELETE the instance? For instance if I stop running it for a while?

Comment: Yes. Data stored on the default Amazon EBS drives is persistent. It's just like a normal computer.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Is is really interesting how Amazon provides all these options for people for free (until a point). Loved it :)

Comment: Be careful. It is unlikely that you will get good performance for TensorFlow from the [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/). Only `t2.micro` instances are included in the Free Tier, but they have limited CPU.